# handling strings with apostrophes passed to javascript generated by jsp and struts 2

Tags: javascript, jsp

in jsp i have

```
<a href="javascript:toggle('<s:property value="company.name"/>')">
```

company names containing apostrophes are generated like so:

```
<a href="javascript:toggle('apostrophe's company')"/>
```

single quotes around names cause problems for company names with the apostrophes. i'd like to get double quotes around the names instead, but i've tried a bunch of things and not having much success. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use "href" for Javascript. It's icky. Instead, do this:

   ```
   <a href='#' onclick="toggle('whatever'); return false">
   ```
2. To deal with quotes in Javascript, I've always written an Expression Language function to perform the Javascript equivalent of `${fn:escapeXml(whatever)}`. I have no idea why that's not part of the standard JSTL/EL function suite, but there you go.  Note that `fn:escapeXml()` is **not** appropriate for use in Javascript source. I'm not sure what your `s:property` thing is; it might be necessary for you to do something like this:

   ```
   <c:set var='companyName'><s:property value='company.name'/></c:set>
   <a href='#' onclick="toggle('${foo:escapeJS(companyName)}'); return false">
   ```